# Warning mkdir() Permission Denied on Google APP Engine PHP Application

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

I am running CodeIgniter PHP Framework on Google APP Engine using flex environment. Everything is going well except for one small issue, I unable to create folder and upload files because of mkdir file permission issue. How can we give permissions when uploading files and create folders?

Your help can save me a lot of time.

Comment: App Engine standard (!) has a memory-based file system mounted at `/tmp` but (!) I'm unsure whether flexible runtimes provides volume mounts like this. You may want to try. However, these are per-instance and not persistent. You may want to consider using Cloud Storage to persist file content but Cloud Storage doesn't give you a mountable file system either and so work is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#the_runtime_config_section) your `runtime_config` by adding the `skip_lockdown_document_root` in `app.yaml`.

> By default, the runtime will set a strict read-only permission on all the files and directories under the document_root directory. When set to true, the runtime will skip changing the permission.

```
runtime_config:
  document_root: .
  skip_lockdown_document_root: true
```

I still recommended to use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/serving-static-files) for storing or serving file on a serverless platform.